# Recommended architecture for Firestore based chat app (scalable)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, architecture, chat

I want to use Firestore as a backend for a chat app.

I can see two opposite DB architectures here:

**A. A single document per message**

pros:

1. small documents (= fast and low bandwidth)
2. easy messages history retrieval (just read older documents)

cons:

1. high cost (touching a lot of documents)
2. high client push rate (number of documents pushed to the DB)

**B. Multiple messages in a single document:**

pros:

1. low cost (touching less documents)
2. low push rate (number of documents pushed to the DB)

cons:

1. large documents (= slower and high bandwidth)
2. hard history management (copy old messages to other documents in order to limit document size)
3. large number of fields per documents (field per message)

Taking all this under consideration, plus the [Firestore's Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices) (with even more limitations), **what would be a good DB architecture**?

Other important Firestore limitations:

1. Keep the rate of write operations for an individual collection under 1,000 operations/second
2. Keep the rate of documents the database pushes to an individual client under 1 document/second
3. Your documents should have fewer than 100 fields

Comment: Instead of coming up with a message sharding technique like that, I'd consider using Firebase's Realtime Database for the messages themselves. If you find yourself hitting the limits of that in traffic for your chat messages, you'll probably need multiple chat rooms already - and can shard those out over multiple database instances.

Comment: I was under the impression that Firestore is superior to Firebase's Realtime Database (no need to download a large tree of data in order to get a single node / field). Am I wrong?
Is it possible / recommended to use both Firebase Realtime Database and Firestore (Realtime Database for messages, Firestore to anything else)?
Can u refer me to an article / code lab / tutorial that suggest a good Firebase / Firestore backend architecture for a chat app?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore